# Translation Invariance and Conserved Momentum for scalar fields

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, field-theory, hamiltonian, crystals

In my Quantum Field Theory Notes, the professor said that the Hamiltonian of the scalar field lattice $\sum_{x} w \big[a_x^\dagger a_x +h/2 \big]$ is translation invariant. This implies that there is a lattice momentum and therefore H will be diagonal in the Fourier space. My question might be a bit basic, but how does the conservation of momentum stem from the invariance? And is it a general rule where [x,y] = -ih $del_x $ and H is invariant in x, so y is conserved?